# Explaining why $\displaystyle {d \over dt}e^{\int_0^tA(s)\,ds} \ne A(t)e^{\int_0^tA(s)\,ds}$ by definition

Tags: proof-writing, matrix-calculus

I've been asked to explain why $\displaystyle {d \over dt}e^{\int_0^tA(s)\,ds} \ne A(t)e^{\int_0^tA(s)\,ds}$ using the definition of $e^A$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

I don't fully understand how they *aren't* equal. Someone please point out where I went wrong:

$$A(t)e^{\int_0^tA(s)\,ds} = A(t) \sum_{n = 0}^\infty{1 \over n!}\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)^n$$

We have been given that

> $${d \over dt}\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)^n = nA(t)\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)^{n-1},$$

which I use to write $$\begin{align}{d \over dt}e^{\int_0^tA(s)\,ds} &= {d\over dt}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty{1 \over n!}\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)^n\right) \\ & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{1 \over n!}{d\over dt}\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)^n\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over(n-1)!}A(t)\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)^{n-1}\end{align}$$

They look equal to me, but likely there's a mistake somewhere. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Where were you given that fact in yellow? I believe it only holds if $A(s)$ commutes with $A(t)$ for all $s,t$ or if $A(s)$ commutes with $A'(s)$. Maybe you forgot to write down that condition as well?

Comment: Given your comments on the accepted answer, you should update your question so that it asks what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that, according to Leibniz's rule,

$$\frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t} \left(\int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s \right) ^n = \frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t} \underbrace {\int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s \dots \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s} _{n \text{ times}} = \color{red} {A(t)} \underbrace{ \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s \dots \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s} _{n-1 \text{ times}} + \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s \color{red} {A(t)} \underbrace{ \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s \dots \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s} _{n-2 \text{ times}} + \dots \underbrace{\int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s \dots \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s} _{n-1 \text{ times}} \color{red} {A(t)} ,$$

where $A(t)$ occupies, in turn, all the positions from $1$ to $n$ in that product, and it is not at all obvious why $A(t)$ should commute with $A(s)$ for $0 \le s < t$.

***If***, on the other hand, these matrices ***do*** commute, then indeed, the result is as you have written, namely

$$\color{red} {A(t)} \ n \left( \int \limits _0 ^t A(s) \ \Bbb d s \right) ^{n-1} .$$

Comment: This looks right, except that the OP's condition in yellow - which the OP claims was given - implies that these matrices do commute.

Comment: @Brick: Absolutely not: the OP has been asked to show why the statement in the question does not hold in general. It doesn't because the statement in yellow does not hold in general, so the OP has been given a mistaken hypothesis.

Comment: If that what he's been asked, then I agree with you.  I understand his question to ask prove it *given the statement in yellow*.

Comment: @Brick: If the statement in yellow is assumed true, then the OP's question makes no sense, since the equality in the title is satisfied.

Comment: Yes.  For sure something is broken in the statement of the question, and your assumption is certainly one reasonable one that would fix the formulation. It would be better for the OP to fix the question though.

Comment: I do apologize, everyone. The matrices are NOT intended to commute. Writing the power rule out like this makes it incredibly clear why the two sides do not equal each other. I was looking through lecture notes that have this rule pointed out but doesn't say what conditions it works under, leaving me confused on this demonstration.

Answer (score -3):

Calling the whole integral at the exponent as $A$ you get:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} e^A = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}(A^k)$$

Now

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} A^k = k\cdot A^{k-1}\cdot \frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d}t}$$

Hence

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} e^A = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}(A^k) = \sum_{k =0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}k\cdot A^{k-1}\frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d}t} = A\cdot\frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d}t} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{k\cdot A^k}{k!}$$

And you can see that it's proven.

Comment: Absolutely not! The relation $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} A^k = k\cdot A^{k-1}\cdot \frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d}t}$ is true only if $A'$ commutes with $A$, which is not necessarily the case here. (Essentially, $(AA)' = A'A + AA'$, and if this is equal to $2AA'$ then it follows that $A'A=AA'$.)

Comment: Answering your comment addressed to me on a different page, I am happy that we have found a way to communicate. If possible, please reconsider your downvoting my answer on this page (I am sure it is your vote :)). Also, we not delete this answer given that it has already accumulated 2 downvotes and, as explained above, does not really answer the question (also, see the OP's clarification below my answer)?

Comment: @AlexM. Indeed, I was reading some of my past questions, and I saw you answered me in 3-4 of them ish, with great answer xD Sometime I'm just too impulsive! In any case, lol I'm sorry! and +1 for you. My answer may be wrong by the way but I'll leave it here because it can help people to understand that there is a necessary condition which is the commutation that has to be satisfied. 
Errors are powerful lessons!